# Magento 2 creating configurable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

Am bit confused how to create a configurable product in Magento 2. The script runs with a self-written module but is executed with a Magento CLI command. I already tried a lot of examples found in google, and the following code is the first which is working without any errors - as result, only the product is changed from simple to configurable, but there are no products associated as configurable in the backend.
The background: I need to import products from csv with simple, parent and child's (configurable associated by size or by size and color). My script is working great and it creates all products as simple products. At the end of everything, the script calls this method to associate the created simple products to the parent products (also created already as simple products) through a loop.

I hope someone can help me to fix this issue!

here is my code (the file is too big to copy here, so I hope my method is enough)

```
public function createConfigurable($parentId, $childIds, OutputInterface $output){
    //$parentId = string, $childIds = array, $output = Magento output object

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
    $position = 0;
    $configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($parentId); // Load Configurable Product

    $configProduct->setTypeId('configurable');
    #$configProduct->save();
    $output->writeln($configProduct->getSku());

    $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds([139,89],$configProduct); //attribute ID of attribute 'size' in my store
    $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configProduct);

    $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

    $configurableProductsData = array();
    $configurableProductsData[25] = array( //['25'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => 'M/L', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => 139, //attribute ID of attribute 'size' in my store
            'value_index' => $this->_moduleHelper->createOrGetId('size', 'M/L'), //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => "5.55" //value for the pricing
        )
    );
    $configurableProductsData[26] = array( //['26'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => 'S/M', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => 89, //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => $this->_moduleHelper->createOrGetId('color', 'blue'), //value of 'blue' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => "8.77" //value for the pricing
        )
    );

    $configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
    $configProduct->save();
    $output->writeln('done');
    return true;
```

}

Comment: Hi, since noone answered my question yet i figured it out by myself and my import with 8000 products is running great now.

for others who might have the same trouble:
the problem was, that i defined the typeId as "configurable" while creating the parent product. Now i create it as "simple" and start my method for configurable. i dont know if there is a much better way, but is working great.

Comment: Would you please clarify what did you mean by (start my method for configurable)? I have the same issue with creating configurable products. Please tell me your solution.

Comment: Hi Abdo Tasks, well since its a while ago my methods are already different but i can tell you my way (am still not sure if there is a better way). I generate an ordinary product with the attribute typeId = "simple". After the creation, my routine decides if it is a parent product with variants. In this case, the important attributes "size", "color", "variantId" of all variants are passed to my method "createConfigurable". Here, the last created product is stored as a parent with the typeId = "configurable" and the corresponding variant ids as well as "size" and "color".